# C++ use function's output as functions input n times

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm sorry for the weird title. I don't know how to word this.
If I have function func()
How do I do this:

```
func(func(func(func(func(x)))))
```

where it repeats N times?

I'm trying to implement Conway's Game of Life. I have a function that takes a vector and outputs another vector, which is the next generation of the input vector. So generation 3's vector would be func(func(func(x))).

Comment: A loop maybe?? Or recursively calling inside? Completely unclear what you're actually asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way, simply using for loop:

```
int x = some_initial_value;
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; ++i)
{
    x = func(x);
}
```

Comment: Oh this was actually common sense. Will mark as answer. Sorry for posting this stupid question I haven't slept in 28 hours

Comment: This only works if `func()` has the same return type as argument type. (Counterexample: an auto lambda that increments `std::integral_type<T, i>).

Comment: @lorro I understand this is the requirement for `func(func(func(func(func(x)))))` as well? I don't really get what your counterexample would look like.

Comment: May the `func` be with you.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen If e.g. `func()` maps `double` to `double`, then it's ok. If it's a template function that maps `std::integral_constant<size_t, i>` to `std::integral_constant<size_t, i + 1>`, then it's not ok, as the two types are different; but you can still apply `func()` to the return type (multiple times even).

Answer (score 2):

While the 'easy way' works in most cases, I'd like to provide you a way to do in in cases where return type (for a given argument type) might differ from argument type:

```
template<size_t i, typename F, typename Arg>
auto times(F f, const Arg& arg) {
    if constexpr (i == 0) {
        return arg;
    } else {
        return times<i - 1>(f, f(arg));
    }
}

// usage: times<5>(func, x);
```